# Can't use "HAVING" "OR" "WHERE" together

Tags: mysql

I want to write a query that selects rows if the last timestamp is newer than 2 days *or* there are 200 children. I am trying to combine a `WHERE` with a `HAVING`, like this:

```
...
WHERE parent.TIMESTAMP < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY_HOUR)
OR HAVING COUNT(parentID) > 199
GROUP BY parent.tID
ORDER BY parent.lastChildID DESC
LIMIT 200
```

but it gives me a syntax error.

How can I use OR between these two conditions?

Comment: use union instead if you need this OR

Comment: `HAVING` is a **post**-aggregation condition, while `WHEN` is a **pre**-aggregation one.  They are separate clauses and cannot be used in the same expression.

Comment: I have to ask, what did you expect OR-ing the WHERE and HAVING together to do differently than just OR-ing the conditions under one or the other.

Comment: @Uueerdo sorry I didn't get it.

now added the whole last part of the query is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: if you are testing for *newer* than 2 days, shouldn't the comparison be *greater than* (not *less* than):  `WHERE parent.TIMESTAMP > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY_HOUR)` ?

Comment: I have 2 different queries. one is more than 2 days old or have at least 200 children

the other one is less than 2 days old or have less than 200 children

but still the question is: if it's possible or not.

Comment: what's wrong with my question? why do you people give negative vote? do I have to impress you with questions? it's just another question jeez

Comment: @idexo I'm not downvoting, but I am guessing because you gave such a small fragment of the query it was barely sufficient to even supply a thorough answer.

Comment: I didn't mean you, it was to the downvoters. sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `HAVING` applies to an aggregate and `WHERE` applies to a rowset, you can't blend them like that. Instead, use a subquery to turn the `HAVING` into a `WHERE` condition on the count:

```
SELECT ...
FROM parent
WHERE parent.TIMESTAMP < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 DAY_HOUR)
OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE tID = parent.tID) > 199
ORDER BY parent.lastChildID DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Answer (score 2):

`HAVING` clause goes after `WHERE`. Its basically, a `WHERE` for `GROUP BY` clause.